# SQL - Joining multiple selects/tables

Tags: sql, join, pervasive

My first query...

```
SELECT
    t1.a, t1.b, t1.c,
    t2.a, t2.b, t2.c

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a

WHERE t1.b = '000000'

AND LENGTH(t1.a) > '5'

AND t1.c <> 'Y';
```

My second query...

```
SELECT
    t1.a,
    t3.b as testMe

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.a = '0' + LEFT(t3.a, 5)

WHERE t1.a = '017941';
```

Both of these queries work fine by themselves, but I need them combined into one result set. Worth noting is that the `where` clause in the second query is there for testing purposes, but when I remove it the whole thing crashes. Not sure if that means I need something to filter by, or it's timing out? The database I'm using is Pervasive.

My failed query...

```
SELECT
    t1.a, t1.b, t1.c,
    t2.a, t2.b, t2.c,
    t3.b as testMe

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a

LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.a = '0' + LEFT(t3.a, 5)

WHERE t1.b = '000000'

AND LENGTH(t1.a) > '5'

AND t1.c <> 'Y';
```

I've shorted my code to better show what I have going on, but the actual code can be found here: http://codeshare.io/A2aB9

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: please be more specific - what is your RDBMS, what is "it" that is crashing?

Comment: are you sure `D` column exists in `t3`?

Comment: I've updated my original post to better show what I have going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use those two sets as subselect statements and join them together.  I pulled your join condition between the two queries out as a separate column in order to keep `testMe` in the result set.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT t1.a t1_a
              , t1.b t1_b
              , t1.c t1_c
              , t2.a t2_a
              , t2.b t2_b
              , t2.c t2_c
         FROM   t1
         LEFT JOIN t2
                ON t1.a = t2.a
         WHERE  t1.b = '000000'
                AND LENGTH(t1.a) > '5'
                AND t1.c <> 'Y') a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   t1.a t1_a
                  , t1.b t1_b
                  , t1.c t1_c
                  , t3.a t3_a
                  , t3.b t3_b
                  , '0' + LEFT(t3.c, 5) t3_c
                  , LEFT(t3.c, 5) AS testMe
           FROM     t1
           LEFT JOIN t3
                    ON t1.a = '0' + LEFT(t3.c, 5)) b
        ON a.t1_a = c.t3_c;
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it didn't do anything. Thank you though.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Did it not return any rows?  Did it return the wrong rows?

Comment: http://codeshare.io/A2aB9 shows my actual code. At the very bottom of your line you have a `c.t3_c` which I think was supposed to be a `b.t3_c`, but either way, I  get a syntax error and it shows `ON a.job_header.<< ???`.